# Unable to consume SOAP webservice in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, rest, soap

I am trying to consume a webservice(Get method )in angularjs.

I have written the code in controller using $http. But, i am not getting any response back, and also i am not sure whether it had hit the URL or not.

All the Corrections or suggestions about the below code are welcome.

(function() {
    'use strict';

```
angular
    .module('ilSaasApp')
    .controller('HomeController', HomeController);

HomeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Principal', 'LoginService', '$state', '$http'];

function HomeController ($scope, Principal, LoginService, $state, $http) {

    function userinfo(){
        alert("Hello");

        $http.get('http://52.38.106.96/Test_Service/WDS_SERVICE.svc/userregistrationbymultipleuseridsforapp/UserIDs?UserIDs=931')
        .then(function(response) {
            alert("Inside fun");
         $scope.data = response.data;

        });

    }
}
```

})();

Comment: When the request is timed-out or aborted, the response is an error with status -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Write error block.. Then check.

```
    function userinfo(){
http.get('http://52.38.106.96/Test_Service/WDS_SERVICE.svc/userregistrationbymultipleuseridsforapp/UserIDs?UserIDs=931')
            .then(function(response) {
                alert("Inside fun");
             $scope.data = response.data;
            }, function(error){
            console.log(error);
    }
    });
```

Comment: I tried with that. Getting the below response.   Object {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: "", headers: function}    Any idea about this ?

Comment: When the request is timed-out or aborted, the response is an error with status -1.